# The [bert] tag has two different meanings

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [bert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert) tag description says:

> BERT and BERT-RPC are an attempt to specify a flexible binary
>   serialization and RPC protocol that are compatible with the
>   philosophies of dynamic languages such as Ruby, Python, PERL,
>   JavaScript, Erlang, Lua, etc.

However, there are questions with this tag that seem to refer to the [BERT - Basic Excel R Toolkit](https://bert-toolkit.com/).

Should a new tag be created to accomodate the BERT Excel toolkit?

Comment: I was really disappointed when I couldn't find an `[ERNIE]` tag...

Comment: From Google, bert-toolkit appears to be far more common than bert-rpc

Comment: On SO, there are 22 questions: 12 toolkit and 10 rpc ...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: could be useful: https://github.com/mojombo/ernie

Comment: We have a tag??

Comment: @Bert sorry but not anymore :), you need to change to bert-toolkit or bert-rpc, pick your choice.

Comment: It appears there is a new [tag:Bert] on the block. Something to do with machine learning!

Answer (score 19):

Yes, we definitely need two different tags, this is what I suggest

1. We create [bert-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-toolkit), the BERT - Basic Excel R Toolkit.
2. We retag (close if off-topic) the toolkit questions.
3. We rename [bert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert) to [bert-rpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-rpc)

The tag names are not perfect since in [bert-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-toolkit) the t stands for toolkit and in [bert-rpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-rpc), the serialization format is only called BERT.

However I think there is no need for a tag specific for the serialization format and since the web site is http://bert-rpc.org this tag should be clear.

As for the bert-toolkit, let's ignore that t = toolkit, we mostly need people to select correct tag and search engines to find questions.

**Result**

User starting to type *bert* can select between [bert-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-toolkit) or [bert-rpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-rpc).

Searching for bert will work with both, if user includes toolkit or rpc they will be directed to correct tag.

Answer (score 3):

Come 2019, there is a new BERT [Big-&-Extending-Repository-of-Transformers](https://github.com/google-research/bert), which is related to this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805. It is a new [language model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model).

There were 6 news questions in the tag all related to that tag. I renamed the tag in its entirety to [bert-language-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-language-model).

So for now, we can consider this small uprising from the bert-walkers to be quashed.

---

Update on June 30th 2019:

Apparently some users went ahead and recreated the [bert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert) tag, and there are 25 questions tagged with it now. I retagged them all to the [bert-language-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-language-model) tag again.

---

Update on Aug 2nd 2019

My monthly check on the health of this tag revealed 5 new questions in the [bert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert) tag, which I retagged.

Comment: I’ve merged [`bert`] into [`bert-language-model`], after retagging the (very few) non-nlp posts. This affected ~250 posts.